# Drop-down menu not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, z-index

I'm having issue with my drop-down menus on both windows and mac versions of chrome. I tried some fixes out there but I can't figure it out.

Any advice would be great! I think there is a z-index issue, but I can't figure out where it is.

Here is the temp site location: http://eyedialabs.ca/oaktreenew/about/

Comment: Could we have some screenshots or some code for when the link stagnates? Just to help others in the future :)

Comment: i tried to add the code, but then it said I couldn't post so many links because I need a 10 reputation? Not to sure, but as it's a menu there are a lot of links!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because an overflow. I realised this because if you gave the drop down `top:-50px;` we could see it, and given that the z-index you have given it is ridiculously high it was going to be the topmost element.

So, after much scouring, I found that it's `header-container`'s `overflow:hidden`. Removing this attribute, fixes the problem.